# How much time does it take to go from Tamsui to Yehliu by bus along the coast?

Tags: public-transport, taiwan

Google Maps claim that the trip takes four and a half hours (bus 862). Does it really take so long to travel 45 km?

Comment: The trip took 1 hr 15 min by bus 862.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. According to the [official website of Yehliu Geopark](http://www.ylgeopark.org.tw/content/info/TrafficContent.aspx), the travel time is more like two hours (translation mine):

> 野柳←→淡水 淡水或基隆客運：班距約30分，車程約2小時。
>   Yehliu <-> Tamsui  Tamshui Bus Company, Ltd. or Keelung Bus Company, Ltd.: Service runs roughly every 30 mins, [and the] travel time [is] roughly 2 hours.

(Interestingly the travel time is omitted in [the english version](http://www.ylgeopark.org.tw/ENG/info/TrafficContent_en.aspx), which reads "Take the express bus (bound to Jinshan) at Tamshui station (near Tamshui MRT Station); alight at Yehliu stop. The bus comes every 30 minutes (the first bus at 05:50am and the last bus at 10:20pm).")

**Edit:** OP further asked what is the number of the "express bus" mentioned above. It is indeed Bus 862, according to [a separate FAQ page from Yehliu Geopark](http://www.ylgeopark.org.tw/ENG/service/FaqList_en.aspx):

> Q : [General] How can one get there?
>   A : [...]
>   3. Danshui to Yehliu – Keelung Bus (no.862) / 1 hour 30 minutes / NTD 90

Comment: How do I find that "express bus"? Does it have a number?

Comment: It appears that it is indeed Bus 862. I will edit the answer to give extra information.

Comment: http://routes.5284.com.tw/ntpcebus/Tw/Map?rid=17528&sec=1 shows the live location of the buses and waiting times, which gives an indication on how long it takes to travel from Tamsui (捷運淡水站, first stop) to Yehliu (野柳, 6th row from the bottom, 2nd from right). You just need to add up the waiting times indicated on the stop where a bus has just passed. Only works when the buses are running (i.e. 06:00 - 20:30 Taiwan Time).

Answer (score 2):

The details for that route show that the actual bus trip takes 3h51m and has *91 stops* along the way.
If each stop is only 1 - 1.5 minutes (just a guess) then that's 2 hours of doing nothing at bus stops, and an average speed of about 25km/hr during travel.
Seems a little slow, but certainly not out of the realm of possibility ...